# Problem with title page when justified in Tufte-Book

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, tufte

I am using Tufte Book template and defined a new paper size (10x7 inches) in `.def` file. Its working fine. When I use justified option in preamble like:`\documentclass[e1paper,symmetric,justified]{tufte-book}`
it justifies the whole text but the title goes out of the margin of the paper:

[image]

but I need to obtain something like this i.e. within margin range:

[image]

One solution I have found is to set the text width as:`\geometry{textwidth=.55\paperwidth}` but it does not look like an organised way and also the text width of whole document decreases.
Another option that i think possible is to remove the justified effect from the title page and put newlines manually but still doesn't look systematic.
Please suggest a solution with methodology. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  (1) It's usual here to post a **minimal** example of your TeX source that shows the problem; you'll get more help if you do, but make sure it's truly minimal!  (2) I thought the whole point of Tufte-Book was to **avoid** justification, none of Tufte's books is ever justified; the theory is that you get more evenly spaced lines and it looks less formal.  So I'm amazed that there is a justified option, but not surprised it doesn't work well.  (3) You might find it easier to start with a simpler class, templates cause so much trouble...

Answer (score 3):

If we redefine the `\maketitlepage` macro to always set the title page ragged right (instead of justified), it will improve the line wrapping. Add the following to the preamble of your document (between the `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` lines):

```
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \begin{fullwidth}%
    \sffamily
    \RaggedRight\sloppy% <-- added this line
    \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
    \vspace{11.5pc}%
    \fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}%
    \vfill
    \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}%
  \end{fullwidth}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \clearpage
}
```

[image: Improved tufte-book title page with justified option]